# Javascript 2-dimensional array: incrementing a specific item's value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array, with integers, and all what I want is to increment a particular item with a number.
The initial state:

```
var arr1=[];
var arr2=[1,2,3];
arr1.push(arr2);
arr1.push(arr2);
arr1.push(arr2);
```

arr1 now looks like this:

```
0:[1, 2, 3]
1:[1, 2, 3]
2:[1, 2, 3]
```

What I want is to increment the [0,0] element of this array with 10, so arr1 should be:

```
0:[11, 2, 3]
1:[1, 2, 3]
2:[1, 2, 3]
```

What I did:

```
arr1[0][0]+=10;
```

But this way the result is:

```
0:[11,2,3]
1:[11,2,3]
2:[11,2,3]
```

What am I missing? Why increments this command all the numbers at position 0 of the array elements?

Comment: you should make a copy of your arr2 before push it inside arr1...

Comment: Because all elements arr1 contain the same object: arr2.

Comment: yes, thanks, now I am aware of that...:-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Objects (Arrays are Objects too) are passed as references. That means that your array looks like this (pseudostructure):

```
 arr2 -> [1, 2, 3]
 arr1 -> [ -> arr2, -> arr2 -> arr2]
```

Therefore `arr1[0]` is just the same as `arr1[1]` or `arr2`. To create three different arrays copy the array:

```
 arr1.push([...arr2]);
```

Comment: thanks, this syntax (spread) was new to me, but now I know...:-)

Answer (score 3):

Because every element of `arr1` is the *same* array, so a change to one is a change to all.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign an array to a variable, you are not making a copy of the array.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = arr1;      // This does NOT create a copy of the array!

console.log(arr1[0]);

arr2[0] = "BOOM!";     // change arr2

console.log(arr1[0]);  // displays "BOOM!" not 1 - arr1 is changed, too!
```

This is because both `arr1` and `arr2` are pointing to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr1=[];
arr1.push([1,2,3]);
arr1.push([1,2,3]);
arr1.push([1,2,3]);

arr1[0][0]+=10;
```

That will give you the desired result.

Your issue is that you've got the same reference to an object three times and when you change that object's value, all references to that object will display the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `var arr2=[1,2,3];`, It will instantiate an object and assign it to `arr2`.

When you run `arr1.push(arr2)`, you are pushing a reference to that object assigned to `arr2`.

In other words, `arr1[0] === arr1[1] === arr1[2]`.

What you need to do is

```
var arr1=[];
arr1.push([1,2,3]);
arr1.push([1,2,3]);
arr1.push([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: OK, I got this, but the data what I have to push to arr1 comes as a result of a for loop, which loop fills arr2, and once it is done, I have to push it to arr1.
That part of knowledge was missing, that only a reference will be pushed to arr1 this way, that's why not only the [0,0] value is incremented, if I did it the way I described...

Comment: In your loop, make sure you create a brand new array for arr2. You must call `arr2 = []` inside the loop before you add values to it, like doing `arr2[0] = 1`, `arr2[1] = 2`, etc. If you do not call `arr2 = []`, then it will never create a new array object, and it will just reuse the same array by overwritting existing values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are not pushing a copy of `arr2` into `arr1`, but a reference (pointer) to `arr2`, which means that you are editing the same array over again.

To avoid that, you should be using [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Instead of `arr1.push(arr2)` do `arr1.push([...arr2])`

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eayLo1t8/) with output:

```
0: Array(3) [ 11, 2, 3 ]
​
1: Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
​
2: Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, and again, learnt something new...:-)